# Python code causing Log Suspends in Sybase

Tags: python, sql, sap-ase

We are seeing a really odd issue where a SQL query run from a Python code is causing Log Suspends due to transaction log getting filled up. It's a simple SELECT query with a small result set. Is there anything with respect to Python which we need to tweak in the SQL code to avoid such issues? Same query when run from a GUI does not cause any issues.

Comment: ask your DBA to extract the actual query that's been submitted to ASE ... pulling the query plan may also help; the DBA should also be able to get more details concerning the log, eg, is the python connection completing its query but leaving a transaction open (which would keep the log from being truncated), or is the python query actually filling up the log?

Comment: Sounds like auto-commit and a transaction being left open. As @markp suggests, engage with your DBA who can acquire more diagnostics.